# Fixing Memory Leak in Django + Scikit-learn

Tags: python, django, django-models, memory-leaks, scikit-learn

How do you diagnose and fix memory leaks involving Django and Scikit-learn?

I'm working on a Django management command that trains several text classifiers implemented using scikit-learn. I'm using all the tricks I know to plug Django memory leaks, including:

1. Setting DEBUG=False
2. Use .iterator() for queryset iteration
3. Use .defer([columns]) to prevent huge column values from being unnecessarily loaded.
4. Clearing cached querysets by periodically calling MyModel.objects.update().
5. Manually invoking gc.collect() to speed up garbage collection.

These techniques have solved all my memory leak problems with long-running Django processes in the past. However, I'm still seeing a massive memory leak with scikit-learn, implying the problem may not be with Django.

My process looks basically like:

```
tmp_debug = settings.DEBUG
settings.DEBUG = False
try:
    documents = Document.objects.all().defer('text')
    for document in documents.iterator():

        classifier = Pipeline([
            ('vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4))),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
            ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())),
        ])

        x_train = document.training_vector
        y_train = document.classification_index

        classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

        obj, _ = SavedClassifier.objects.get_or_create(document=document)
        _, fn = tempfile.mkstemp()
        joblib.dump(classifier, fn, compress=9)
        obj.classifier = b64encode(open(fn, 'rb').read())
        os.remove(fn)
        obj.save()

        Document.objects.update()
        gc.collect()
finally:
    settings.DEBUG = tmp_debug
```

Each document object contains several pages of text (in the "text" field). I have about 50 document records, and after parsing 5 documents, the script is consuming about 4GB of memory, having steadily increased over time.

Is there any way I can diagnose and fix this memory leak, short of running my script once for each document?

Comment: Weird: maybe there is an issue in the liblinear bindings: can you try to replace LinearSVC by MultinomialNB or PassiveAggressiveClassifer for instance?

Comment: @ogrisel, It doesn't seem limited to LinearSVC. The same high memory usage happens with MultinomialNB and PassiveAggressiveClassifer.

Comment: Alright, then you will have to track it done with a tool like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/meliae or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler